# Run function at 60fps

Tags: javascript, setinterval, frame-rate

I'm currently using `setInterval( () => {}, 16 )` to run my code 60fps, but this makes the code run at 62.5fps, which makes the game movements jump forward twice the speed for a few frames per second. Using interval 17 makes the game movement freeze for a frame every once in a while.

How can I run the code truly at 60fps for maximum smoothness?

Comment: What about `1000/60` ?

Comment: Use a JS game engine, like Babylon.js / Phaser 3 / etc. -> https://www.html5gamedevs.com/ `setInterval` can drift.

Comment: framerate depends of the speed of your code and the machine which runs the code as well. you can't just set a timer and expect same framerate on every devices.

Comment: @JeremyThille 1000 / 60 causes the same problem as using 16, it's jittery.

Comment: @Marc, I already wrote the whole game, just now realized it's jittery, I'm not gonna use a game engine and rewrite the game.

Comment: @tempacc Thats fine, but why reinvent the wheel? Sometimes you have to acknowledge that your approach was just bad and there are better solutions.

Comment: @Marc Well I wrote the game in Javascript to keep it as light as possible, (and to learn canvas) and yes, the approach was bad, but I think I'll get it smooth without rewriting the whole game. (Going to beusing Window.requestAnimationFrame with 0 and deltatime)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [Window.requestAnimationFrame([callback])](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame)

That way your application will be called when it's time to render, wether the monitor is 30hz, 60hz or 120hz or more.

See this example from https://css-tricks.com/using-requestanimationframe/ on how to use it if the MDN documentation isn't clear enough.

```js
var globalID;

function repeatOften() {
  $("<div />").appendTo("body");
  globalID = requestAnimationFrame(repeatOften);
}

  globalID = requestAnimationFrame(repeatOften);

$("#stop").on("click", function() {
  cancelAnimationFrame(globalID);
});
$("#start").on("click", function() {
  globalID = requestAnimationFrame(repeatOften);
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: orange;
  float: left;
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
}
#stop {
  left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="start">start</button>
<button id="stop">stop</button>
```

Comment: This combined with deltatime solves the problem. Thank you.